# How to update an associated entity with Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

Frame has a unidirectional oneToOne association to Photo.

- I guess every Frame is associated with a Photo now.
- I also guess that a Photo stores no information about the Frame.
- I want to know which Photo is in a Frame (Have a Photo in a Frame)
- I don't want to know about in which Frame a Photo is located
- I assume that I'm able to have a Photo in **more** than one Frames!

By now everything worked as expected:

```
$photo = new Photo();
$another_photo = new Photo();
$frame = new Frame();
$frame->setPhoto($photo);

$em->persist($frame);
$em->flush();
```

Frame and two Photos are created and the Frame is connected with $photo in the DB. I can query $frame and get $photo with getPhoto().

But I want to update the Photo of a Frame now and it does not work:

```
$frame = $em->getRepository('Frame')->findOneById(id_of_frame);
$frame->setPhoto($another_photo);
$em->persist($frame);
$em->flush();
```

And get a Doctrine Error:
*A new entity was found through the relationship 'Frame#Photo' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity. Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship.*

I can set a cascade="persist" inside the Frame OneToOne relation and the error does not occur any more but I get a new error about not persisted color which I use in the Photo which I truly do not set and want :(

Why do I get the error at all? Why do I need to persist cascade the Frame and the Photo?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your doctrine mapping config.

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating $anothor_photo?
Since it is already in the database, you will need to do something like:
$another_photo = $entityManager->getReference('Photo',$another_photo_id);

By the way, the whole cascade thing can become quite confusing.  I think you will find that it safer to just persist new photos when you create them.

Comment: Thank's very much for the getReference tip. I was foolish enough to be setting an existing object to a relationship, and doctrine was pretending it didn't know about it.